# Hive:- Select on partition column gives result even when table is truncated

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table in hive which is partitioned on a column.
I truncate the table and I do 2 selects on them.

1. Select count(*) from table, I get the result as 0. Which is expected.

But If I do a select on the partition column, I get results instead of null rows which I expected.

```
Select distinct <paritition column> 
from table
```

Result:

```
partition value 1
partition value 2
......
```

I can see in hdfs that the partition folders still exists , though they are empty. I expected the metadata to get updated after I did the truncate.

I am not sure why I am getting the above result

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: This is expected. Partitions are physical folder - they will exist even if table is empty. They will contain no files so actually there is no data in the table. YOu need to drop partition if you want to remove them.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing. I see that if I use Impala to do the select partition column on the same table after truncate, I get 0 rows. Impala and hive work differently in this regard?

Comment: in implala, could you pls run `invalidate stats mytable`  and try?

Comment: I did a invalidate metadata on the table before the select on partition column. I get  0 rows